# React native Accordion

Tags: react-native, accordion

I'm new to react native and I have been working on a small project where I have use for accordion component after searching I found [this](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-accordion)
which I tried to implement the thing is how can I make this component reusable cause I have different data for different components. I want to do this without using a JSON file as data source. 
for example

```
getInitialState() {
   var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
return {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(_.range(25)),
```

here in datasource i want to pass data for different components

can anyone help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animated Accordion/ Drawer/ Drop-down/ Collapsible-card in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060475/animated-accordion-drawer-drop-down-collapsible-card-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

The project that you are using was last updated 2 years ago. You may want to consider using this one instead: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible

Answer (score 0):

There's also another project named [react-native-accordion-wrapper](https://github.com/aliunco/react-native-accordion-wrapper), and you can customize it in any way you'd like, and it's so easy to use:

```
<Accordion
    dataSource={[
       { title: 'header one', child: <Component1 /> },
       { title: 'header two', child: <Component2 /> },
    ]}
/>
```

you can also use another child component from this library named `AccordionItem` if you need more customization.